# How to create a dynamic form where fields not belonging to a table/form influence the option choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

I am able to create an order form, where a user can fill in a bike_type and the form consequently render bikes belonging to this bike_type.

- Orders are linked to bikes via a join table (as there is a many to many relationship between them).
- A bike belong to a bike_type
- A bike_type belongs to a bike_store

**Issue**

When the form re-renders e.g. (i) validation is raised, so 'new' action is rendered again or (ii) when I want to edit the order:

- *All fields are repopulated with previous data, except for the fields for bike_type and bike (these are empty).*

**Code**

Order controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @bike_store = BikeStore.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order = Order.new
    @order.order_bikes.build
    @bike_type_list = @bike_store.bike_types
    @bikes = []

    # Display bikes for category
    if params[:bike_type].present?
      @bikes = BikeType.find(params[:bike_type]).bikes
    end
    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json {
        render json: {bikes: @bikes}
      }
      end
    end
    authorize @order
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @bike_store = BikeStore.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order.bike_store = @bike_store
    authorize @order
    @order.save
    if @order.save
      redirect_to bike_store_path(@bike_store)
    else
      @bike_type_list = @bike_store.bike_types
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @bike_store = BikeStore.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @bike_type_list = @bike_store.bike_types
    @bikes = @order.bikes
    authorize @order
  end

  def update
    @bike_store = BikeStore.find(params[:bike_store_id])
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @bikes = @order.bikes
    if @order.update(order_params)
      redirect_to redirect_to bike_store_path(@bike_store)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
      authorize @order
  end

    private
  def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:arrival, :departure, :payment,
      order_bikes_attributes: [:id, :bike_id, :bike_quantity, :_destroy,
        bikes_attributes: [:id,:name, :bike_type_id,
          bike_types_attributes: [:id, :name]]])
  end
end
```

views/order/_form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@bike_store, @order] do |f|%>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :order_bikes do |order_bike| %>
    <%= order_bike.simple_fields_for :bikes do |bike| %>
      <%= bike.input :bike_type, collection: @bike_type_list, input_html:{
        id: "bike_type"
      }%>
    <%= order_bike.association :bike, collection: @bikes, input_html:{
      value: @bikes.object_id,
      id: "dynamic-bikes"
    } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<script >
  // dynamic bikes for change category
  $(document).on("change", "#bike_type", function(){
    var bike_type = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/bike_stores/<%= @bike_store.id %>/orders/new",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {bike_type: bike_type},
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {
      var bikes = response["bikes"];
      $("#dynamic-bikes").empty();

      $("#dynamic-bikes").append('<option>Select bike</option>');
      for(var i=0; i< bikes.length; i++){
        $("#dynamic-bikes").append('<option value="' + bikes[i]["id"] + '">' + bikes[i]["name"] + '</option>');
      }
    }
  });
  });
  // dynamic bikes for releading form (e.g. new)
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var bike_type = $("#bike_type").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/bike_stores/<%= @bike_store.id %>/orders/new",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {bike_type: bike_type},
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('AJAX Error: ' + status + error);
      },
      success: function (response) {

      var bikes = response["bikes"];
      $("#dynamic-bikes").empty();

      $("#dynamic-bikes").append('<option>Select bike</option>');
      for(var i=0; i< bikes.length; i++){
        $("#dynamic-bikes").append('<option value="' + bikes[i]["id"] + '">' + bikes[i]["name"] + '</option>');
      }
    }
  });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: There is no reason the user should be passing that much information. Especially not the nested attributes. The user should just be passing ids that point to a normalized table of products, and the quantities for it. I think you're basically just giving yourself a huge mass assignment vulnerability here.

Comment: @Max, that's an interesting view, as what I'm currently doing seems indeed too complex and vulnerable. As this is the first time I'm working in an e-commerce-like setting I will open a new question with more of a conceptual question how to attack this problem of dealing with orders, bike_types and associated bikes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to preserve the "state" of the form-page from before form submit into the same form-page after submit (when validation error occurs). Normally, **you'll just need to "replay" the Javascript events that have happened in the previous page**, and so "usually", below should be already sufficient enough to make it work:

### TL;DR:

#### app/views/order/_form.html.erb:

```html
<!-- ... -->
<!-- ... -->
<script>
  // on document ready (after all DOM elements have been loaded):
  $(function() {
    // replay event by immediately triggering a
    // "change" event on your `#bike_type` input
    $('#bike_type').change();
  })

  // dynamic bikes for change category
  $(document).on("change", "#bike_type", function(){
    // ...
    // ...
  })

  // ...
  // ...
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work all the time especially if you intentionally do not want to `trigger` change immediately after page load. If it doesn't fully work properly, let me know the other repercussions of my code above, and I'll update my answer above, if it's easily  fixable.

Comment: thank you so much for the elaborate explanation. Just to clarify, you are suggesting to: (i) leave the 'change' event as it is (ii) alter the ```$(document).ready(function(){ ``` by adding ```$('#bike_type').change(); ``` before the last line?

Comment: @techquestion The `...` means the rest of your code; so i) is correct, and ii) you can add that `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` anywhere inside the topmost context of `<script>`, because regardless where you put that (before or after), the `DOMContentLoaded` event happens asynchronously, anyway

Comment: Thanks for the context! It does not seem to work, but I am contemplating following a new approach for my order as this seems too complex to function properly.